# Kernel Make requires libssl0.9.8?

Tags: linux-kernel, software-installation, shared-library

Im getting the error below while running make while trying to recompile kernel linux 4.15.0 for my Ubuntu 18.04 VM.

```
openssl: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I obtain the kernel source code using the

```
apt-get source linux-image-unsigned-$(uname -r)
```

command. I have installed the newest `libssl` and installed 0.9.8 using

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openssl098/libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb
```

Any ideas?? It seems weird that any newish kernel would require 0.9.8 (**I tried installing the most up to date kernel from kernel.org also and had the same issue**)

Comment: What does `command -v openssl` say?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/openssl

Answer (score 0):

The kernel build uses `openssl`, and it’s picking up an old `openssl` in `/usr/local/bin` — that’s what needs `libssl0.9.8`.

To fix this, remove or rename the `openssl` binary in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/openssl{,.bak}
```

That way the kernel build will use the version in `/usr/bin`, which should work fine.